# Change Text Color of the selected item in a ListView

Tags: qt, listview, qml

Let me start by saying that I am pretty new to QML.

I have a `ListView` (with `model` and `delegate`), it works fine in my model but I would like to change the `color` (currently `color: skin.gray`) of the selected item to something else when the item is the `currentIndex`-item.

```
ListView {
    id: menuBody_listview
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    currentIndex: 0
    clip: true

    highlight: highlighter
    highlightFollowsCurrentItem: true

    Behavior on opacity {
        NumberAnimation { property: "opacity"; duration: 300; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
    }

    anchors {
        top: menuHeader_listview.bottom
        bottom: parent.bottom
    }
    model: ListModel {
        ListElement {
            itemIconLeft: 'images/icons/menu/pause.png'
            itemText: "Cancel"
            itemIconRight: 'images/icons/menu/take-me-home.png'
        }
        ListElement {
            itemIconLeft: 'images/icons/menu/pause.png'
            itemText: "Mute"
            itemIconRight: 'images/nill.png'
        }
        ListElement {
            itemIconLeft: 'images/icons/menu/repeat.png'
            itemText: "Repeate"
            itemIconRight: 'images/nill.png'
        }
    }
    delegate: MenuBodyItem {
        width: menuBody_listview.width
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        iconLeft: itemIconLeft
        message: itemText
        iconRight: itemIconRight
    }
}
```

Following is the code for the item which is being populated, `ManuBodyItem.qml`.

Item {

```
width: 100
height: 50
property alias iconLeft: menuitem_icon_start.source
property alias message: menuitem_text.text
property alias iconRight: menuitem_icon_end.source

RowLayout {
    spacing: 20
    anchors.fill: parent

    Image {
        id: menuitem_icon_start
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
        anchors {
            left: parent.left
            verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: menuitem_text

        anchors {
            left: menuitem_icon_start.right
            verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            verticalCenterOffset: -2
            leftMargin: 20
        }

        color: skin.gray
        font {
            family: "TBD"
        }
    }

    Image {
        id: menuitem_icon_end
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
        source: iconRight
        anchors {
            right: parent.right
            verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From your example:

`color: skin.gray` is used for the Text element which will change the color of the text and not it's background viz. i understood you want.

You can use a Rectangle element here which can act as a background component to set the background color.
So instead of Item root element in the delegate you can use Rectangle. So MenuBodyItem.qml will look as

```
Rectangle {

    width: 100
    height: 50
    ...
}
```

Now to set background color to the Rectangle if it is current one you can use `ListView.isCurrentItem` to check.
So,

```
Rectangle {
    color: ListView.isCurrentItem ? "cyan" : "lightblue"
    width: 100
    height: 50
}
```

and now finally you will have to set the clicked item as the current one which can be done in the MouseArea of the Delegate Item

```
delegate: MenuBodyItem {
    width: menuBody_listview.width
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    iconLeft: itemIconLeft
    message: itemText
    iconRight: itemIconRight
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: menuBody_listview.currentIndex = index
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Skin.gray is just a property and defines a color. Other than that I can not understand your solution. I just wanted to know how to perform a color transition inside the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ListView`'s [isCurrentItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#isCurrentItem-prop) attached property:

```
Text {
    id: menuitem_text

    anchors {
        left: menuitem_icon_start.right
        verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        verticalCenterOffset: -2
        leftMargin: 20
    }

    color: itemDelegate.ListView.isCurrentItem ? "red" : skin.gray
    font {
        family: "TBD"
    }
}
```

Note that you have to give your root delegate item an ID in order to qualify the expression above:

```
Item {
    id: itemDelegate

    RowLayout {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

You can see the same approach used in the example I linked to.

Comment: This looks bad when the highlight rect is animating, text color changes before the highlight even reaches the item.